# Datatable text overflow not truncating

Tags: javascript, css, datatable, overflow, truncate

I am trying to truncate some text in a column of my datatable. All it seems to be doing is, making the text one line, and running way off to the side of the page and not truncating it. Below is the css I have in place. I am trying to keep the text to one line and truncating the rest with ellipsis.

CSS:

```
table.dataTable td {
    -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
    box-sizing: content-box;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9700039/hide-part-of-the-text-html-css-javascript/24156690#24156690

check the answers here...

Comment: See this links:    http://davidwalsh.name/css-ellipsis AND  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19134075/truncating-big-text-value-in-pdatatable-and-exporting-the-table-with-the-full-t